# My Excel file won't load all rows because it's too large

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble fully opening an Excel file as it's too large (1.1GB). I'm currently selecting:
*Data > Get Data From Text/CSV* and choosing the file from there.

When I select *Load Data* it begins to export the information on to my worksheet but eventually the number of rows loaded freezes and I get the Error Message "Load to worksheet failed - file too large".

Is there any alternate way I could open this file? Is there any way I could extract data based on column content, for example, only extract rows where date in column A = 01/01/2000?

Comment: Is Excel really the right tool here? Excel isn't a database. Why not use a proper database for your data?

Comment: ^^^ A csv file is not an Excel file. Excel should not be used for files this large. `pandas` could do this quite easily.

Comment: Yes I think using a database may be the solution here. Thanks all for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a 32-bit version of Microsoft Office, you can try to download the 64-bit version. It should be capable of opening your file.

Otherwise, you could use a script to access the data (i.e. some python modules, like pandas or openpyxl).